# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "<": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

Can Anyone Help Me to solve this i had error sqlite3.OperationalError: near "<": syntax error i think that from the sql but still stucking there

```
def getProfile(id):
       connect = sqlite3.connect('C:///Users///Marvin///Desktop///Opencv-face-detection-python-master///SQL///sql.db')
       cur = connect.cursor()
       connect.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id="+str(id))
       profile=None
       for row in cur:
         profile=row
       cur.close()
       return profile
```

Comment: What *is* `id`? Also don't put values into queries by string concatenation, use the placeholders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot replicate your error in my testing.

While I was testing your code, I notice a problem with

```
connect.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id="+str(id))
```

I think it should be

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id="+str(id))
```

That works during my testing. Please let me know if this works or not. By changing this, the function returns a result and I was able to get the result.

If you don't mind, I have one extra piece of advice for you. The way you wrote your query is very prone to SQL Injection attacks as shown [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html). I would recommend you to structure your query in the following way.

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=?",str(id))
```

Comment: `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID=?",str(id))`                                             i'm using this but show next error is                                                  `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 22 supplied.`

Comment: The second parameter to `execute` should be a tuple: `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=?", (str(id),) )`.

Comment: What is in your id? is it just a integer or a list? If you print(id), what do you see?